# iOS output stream music in background

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, ios6, audio-streaming

to cut story short Im developing an app thats like Sonos. That is, Im trying to stream music from the iPod library to a hardware over wifi. Hence the sound will come out of a hardware that is connected to the iPhone by wifi.

Doing this is easy enough when the app is foreground but in the background the app will be terminated. It is different when outputting the audio in the background in the iPhone device itself.

Also I notice that Sonos supports this feature only for iOS 6 so I wonder if theres some new magical API that allows this.

I hope any of you gurus can guide me to the right path.

Comment: So I guess `UIBackgroundModes` set towards `audio` does not do the job?

Comment: Yes, it is not enough. Because the app is supposed to stream the audio towards the hardware

Comment: @SamuelKitono You can resolve it by mirroring playback, for example when you want to play remotely, you set audio session that mixes and plays in the background and then you also play the same music locally, with your tracks for your particular resources being muted, this is not a nice way, but it will do the job

Comment: @SamuelKitono  I am also facing same problem. Have you got solution? Could you tell me how to handle that approach.